# Load plugin script in specific page

Tags: plugins

I tried to use the code below in version 4.0 of my wordpress and you can not load the file you wish only a specific page. Is there any way to do this with other code?

The plugin in question is the Multi-column Tag Map

```
function wpa_scripts() {
// if this is not the contact page, remove the script
if( ! is_page( '' ) ){
    wp_dequeue_script('');
}
}
// adjust priority to make sure this runs after the plugins add their scripts/styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_scripts', 100 );
```

Comment: Remove the `!` operator. `if( ! is_page( '' ) )` means in plain English, *if we are **not** on a page, then do something*. You would want to change this to `if( is_page( 'PAGE_ID' ) )` which means *if we are on page PAGE_ID, do something*

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing to make sure of, you must put the page id in the brackets for the "is_page()" function. If your page ID was 12, you'd use it like this:

`if( ! is_page( 12 ) ){`

You can find a page's id by editing it and looking in the URL for "post=". The Page ID will be directly after the "=" sign in the address bar.

Comment: Hello, i know that, even used in the code, but it did not work. The script remained active for all other pages and posts.

Comment: Update your question with your new code changes.